# Indexing new dataframes into new columns with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I need to create a new dataframe from an existing one by selecting multiple columns, and appending those column values to a new column with it's corresponding index as a new column

So, lets say I have this as a dataframe:

```
A B C D E F
0 1 2 3 4 0
0 7 8 9 1 0
0 4 5 2 4 0
```

Transform into this by selecting columns B through E:

```
A index_value
1 1
7 1
4 1
2 2
8 2
5 2
3 3
9 3
2 3
4 4
1 4
4 4
```

So, for the new dataframe, column `A` would be all of the values from columns `B through E` in the old dataframe, and column `index_value` would correspond to the index value [starting from zero] of the selected columns.

I've been scratching my head for hours. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Python3, Using pandas & numpy libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Another way

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   0   1   2   3   4   0
1   0   7   8   9   1   0
2   0   4   5   2   4   0

# Select columns to include

start_colum ='B'
end_column ='E'
index_column_name ='A'

#re-stack the dataframe

df = df.loc[:,start_colum:end_column].stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame()

#Create the "index_value" column 

df['index_value'] =pd.Categorical(df.index).codes+1

df.rename(columns={0:index_column_name}, inplace=True)

df.set_index(index_column_name, inplace=True)

df

    index_value
A   
1   1
7   1
4   1
2   2
8   2
5   2
3   3
9   3
2   3
4   4
1   4
4   4
```

Comment: So, I tried this and apparently I cant do `df = df.loc[:,start_colum:end_column].stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame()` because I'm trying `df.loc[:,9:15]` to select columns `9,10,11,12,13,14,15` by their index. How could I select columns by their index, and still get this to work? In my actual csv file, there aren't any headers to select from, as they're all ints.

Comment: Reference: `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class "pandas.core.indexes.base.Index"> with these indexers [9] of <class "int">
`

Comment: If you are going to use numeric indexes try iloc[] instead of loc[], I used loc[] in the code because I was referring to the columns by name. 'B' instead of 1.

Comment: For some reason, index_value is starting at 3. I'm selecting iloc[9:15], shouldn't the output be starting at 9, and numerically increase to 15?

Comment: loc[ a:b , c:d] means select rows a thru b and columns c thru d. loc[: , c:d] means select all rows and columns c thru d. I love is the same but based on the indexes. What are you trying to select?

Comment: Select columns 9,11,12,13,14,15 by their index.

Comment: What would be column 15 ? The original dataframe has columns a thru f , which is 6, and the reshaped dataframe has only 1 colum , or are you looking at a larger dataset? Anything I can do to help let me know.

Comment: I have a larger dataset with 29 columns, and about 400 rows.

Comment: Ok, Just remember that indexes start at 0 so df.iloc[0,0] will give you the value in the intersection of the first row and the first colum.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem anyways. Quick question though, how would I remove any rows that contain 0's in them after reshaping the dataframe. A lot of data in the "A" column contain zero's, that I don't need.

Comment: df[df['index_value] != 0]

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything, it still has the zero's, and I tried using `df[df['index_value'] != 0]`, and `df[df['A'] != 0] `

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
df = pd.melt(df[['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']])
# Or df['variable'] = df[['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']].melt()
df['variable'].shift().eq(df['variable'].shift(-1)).cumsum().shift(-1).ffill()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    variable  value
0        1.0      1
1        1.0      7
2        1.0      4
3        2.0      2
4        2.0      8
5        2.0      5
6        3.0      3
7        3.0      9
8        3.0      2
9        4.0      4
10       4.0      1
11       4.0      4
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid question, but could I use `df = pd.melt(df.iloc[:, [1,4])` as a means to select columns [1,2,3,4] by their index?

Comment: @TylerWayne yeah that works too don't forget to accept mine or WenYoBen's answer if they works

Comment: `0,1.0
1,2.0
2,3.0
3,4.0
4,5.0
5,6.0
6,7.0
7,8.0
8,9.0`

Comment: I believe maybe the columns aren't getting selected properly, will update soon

Answer (score 0):

This is just `melt`

```
df.columns = range(df.shape[1])
s = df.melt().loc[lambda x : x.value!=0]
s
    variable  value
3          1      1
4          1      7
5          1      4
6          2      2
7          2      8
8          2      5
9          3      3
10         3      9
11         3      2
12         4      4
13         4      1
14         4      4
```